# field set to undefined when finding document by field value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB table with a lat field and a long field. I want to add a new field which is an Array. When I do this, the fields are set correctly:

```
var a = db.places.findOne();
var currentId = a._id;
var longitude = a.long;
var latitude = a.lat;
var lonLatPair = [longitude,latitude];

db.places.update(
    { _id: currentId},
    { $set : {location: lonLatPair}}
)
```

However, when I use the _id of a, doing this they are set to undefined.

```
a = db.places.find({ _id : "ced25473-2786-4cab-990b-5179b74e6540"});
var currentId = a._id;
var longitude = a.long;
var latitude = a.lat;
var lonLatPair = [longitude,latitude];

db.places.update(
    { _id: currentId},
    { $set : {location: lonLatPair}}
)
```

Is there a way that I can do a query based on a field value and set these correctly? I don't understand why the first works and the second does not.

Comment: what will you see if you do your second attempt, and output `lonLatPair`? Most probably it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined because in your second example, `a` is a [**`cursor`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) - pointer to the result set of a query, whilst in your first example you are using the [**`findOne()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) method which returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria. If multiple documents satisfy the query, this method returns the first document according to the natural order which reflects the order of documents on the disk thus your fields are set correctly. What you probably need is to use the [**`toArray()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) method on the cursor **`find()`**:

```
var currentId, longitude, longitude, lonLatPair; 

a = db.places.find({ _id: "ced25473-2786-4cab-990b-5179b74e6540"}).toArray();
if (a.length > 0) { 
    currentId = a[0]._id;
    longitude = a[0].long;
    latitude = a[0].lat;
    lonLatPair = [longitude, latitude];     
}
```

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, simply use the **`findOne()`** method with the `_id` query specified as the argument :

```
var currentId, longitude, longitude, lonLatPair,
    a = db.places.findOne({ _id: "ced25473-2786-4cab-990b-5179b74e6540"});
currentId = a._id;
longitude = a.long;
latitude = a.lat;
lonLatPair = [longitude, latitude];

db.places.update(
    { _id: currentId},
    { $set : {location: lonLatPair}}
);
```